# UDP frequent sendTo() on client side fails receiveFrom() call on server side

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, udp, mbed

I'm trying to build a network benchmark like netio.

`sendTo()` and `receiveFrom()` are working fine when they are not called in a fast loop.

But when I send 1KB data packets in a loop to my server only the first `receiveFrom()` loop works, all further loops return `-1`

How can this happen and what can be done? Asking for general advise because I'm on *mbed stm board* (server side)

Comment: UDP doesn't guarantee delivery. If you send too fast, you can overflow buffers and packets will be lost.

Comment: But that shouldn't cause `recvfrom()` to return `-1`. That only happens if there's an error in the call. What is the error message you get from `perror()`?

Comment: @Barmar Thats where I was headed, but then I reread `receiveFrom`, not `recvfrom` and went, "Errr? .Net?" What network library is in use here?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message because I'm on mbed, I only get -1. can I use perror() with mbed?

Comment: https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Socket

Comment: @gozilla1988 you could try. If not, you can at least print the value of errno, the errno value when recveiveFrom fails will be a hint as to what is wrong. Though perhaps there's just a plain normal bug in your code too, such as a buffer overflow.

Comment: `perror` better be there. Pretty sure it's in the C standard.

Comment: I use the original netio code and tweek it for my stm board, so the algorithms are ok. and the buffer should be too. the buffer size is 65536 bytes. receiveFrom only returns once with 1KB. is then only 1KB on the buffer or is it already filled up in the background? if thats the case maybe its too full. i will test tomorrow. it's late over here

Comment: when I make progress/ find the error code, should i post it here and you get a notification or should I post a new question because this, then old, thread is buried?

Comment: To be honest, that would probably be the right answer for you. Probably the wrong answer for the site, but if you can make a solid, well-targeted question that will help future coders with the same problem you'll likely be forgiven and this one will be garbage collected.